# switching to the pop up window after clicking on write reviews

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

while performing the automation testing on google reviews using python selenium and after we click on the write review option suddenly the one pop-up window will appear how to switch to that window and perform action on web element on that window.

I tried with help of locators but it didn't help me and also i tried using iFrames but it is not working fine can some one help me resolving this problem.

Comment: You need to edit your question and share your code trials, error stack and the URL if it can be accessed by public.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.